# How to remove "-Year" option in views date exposed filter dropdown?

Tags: date, drupal, drupal-exposed-filter

Can't alter it's values with hook_form_alter because element of type date_select doesn't have #options array.

Answer (score 2):

['#options'] array available in form validation callback. To overwrite form element make sure you passing $form argument by reference:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $view = $form_state['view'];
  if ($view->name == 'press_center' && $view->current_display == 'page') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'MY_MODULE_date_filter_validate';
  }
}

function MY_MODULE_date_filter_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['year_month']['value']['month']['#options'] = array(1=>'Jan',2=>'Feb',3=>'Mar');
}
```